# How to run a standalone linux app built with flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-linux

I have built a linux app with flutter using : `flutter build linux` in my ubuntu VM.

My goal is to run this linux app in an embbeded device so i need to copy the required files to this device (running under linux) and then execute the equivalent of `main.dart`  in the embbeded device.

I am very new to this, so what are the directories / files needed to run the standalone linux app ?

I see a `bundle` directory inside the `/build/linux/x64` folder after running `flutter build linux` but i don't understand any files written inside / how to execute the whole app... And even if it's the correct directory to copy in my embbeded device.

EDIT :
Running the app by trying to execute `./my_app_name` on the corresponding file gives the following error :

```
-bash: ./my_app_name: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

And i am guessing this is a not a shell script...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After running the command `flutter build linux`, you should find all the required files to run it in `build/linux/release/bundle`

Just copying/pasting it on your device shall work (if the device is supported).

There is an official guide explaining how to build and release your app onto the Snap Store: https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/linux

**Important note :**
As described in the [official documentation](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/tools/sdk/release-notes/supported-platforms), a Flutter app supports Linux Debian, 64-bit. Meaning that if you try to run your app on a 32-bit distribution, it won't start.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. Do you mean there is no "execution" script to run or anything ? The user should be allowed to run it or not so i am quite surprised there is no file to run to run the whole app.

Comment: I have seen this documentation but i have no plans releasing on the snap store for now, thanks anyway.

Comment: There is no script generated, you should only have your binary in the folder linked in my answer. You should see a file which has your app name, and a simple ./your_app_name should work (can't test it rn, i'm not on my Linux)

Comment: oh alright thanks for the explanation, will try it out as soon as i can. There is indeed a file with my project name

Comment: It doesn't work unfortunately i will update the question with the provided result

Comment: Did you run the command on your working computer or on your other device ?

Comment: on my other device, i have not tried on my working computer you are right

Comment: You are actually right it's working fine ! this means that it's my other device that has a problem to run the script. Thank you so much

Comment: https://docs.flutter.dev/development/tools/sdk/release-notes/supported-platforms <-- Flutter requires a Unix system 64-bit to be able to run. It may change in the future

Comment: Update your answer with your comment with supported Unix version and i will accept it

Comment: The answer was updated with the missing infos